# Check if git repository is behind master HEAD

Tags: git, github

How to check git submodule repositories status before pulling?

You can do this to pull all submodules

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master
```

How to check status of all submodules to see if they are behind master HEAD and with how many commits they are behind

## update

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git fetch origin master

git submodule foreach --recursive git rev-list --count HEAD..master
```

Comment: I think there is a simpler (and slightly faster) command to pull all submodules: `git submodule update --recursive --remote`

Comment: "*…how many commits they are behind…*" This can be calculated only after fetching remote commits locally. So in your command replace `pull` with `fetch` and then run `git status` or `git branch -vv` (or any other plumbing or porcelain commands to calculate ahead/behind status) recursively.

Comment: @phd: you do need the `git fetch`, but since submodules are always (what, always? well, hardly never...) in detached-HEAD mode you will need `git rev-list --count HEAD..master`.

Comment: @torek have updated my question. After running the two commands `0` was returned for each submodule but after running `git submodule foreach --recursive git pull origin master` one submodule had a new commit which was retrieved